# rewriterule -> http://www.domain.com to a page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How do I write a rule that'll take a user to /data/test.php when he accesses the site using http://www.domain.com (and nothing else after that (maybe a slash)). There are no other pages in my root folder, not even index.html. All other rules require something after the domain, but if I type only the domain I get the directory list. Any idea how its done. I did the one below, but it redirects everything (any request path) to the specified file.

```
RewriteRule ^/? /data/test.php
```

Comment: Which folder does it redirect to? Why do you think that the above line would do that? What does your test.php contain? (maybe **IT** redirects to the folder). It is **VERY** difficult to find solution to a problem with so many unknowns.

Comment: @GermannArlington It redirects to /data/test.php which is a "Hello World" page. Nothing more than that. So now www.domain.com/us/ca also goes to /data/test.php. But I only need www.domain.com to be redirected there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try RewriteRule ^/?$ /data/test.php